# Close opened sockets in child process

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a SIP server (daemon) which is listening on tcp socket 5060. Now in this parent process I create a child process and do something in child. 
Now, What happens is when I close this tcp socket in parent process and try to create again (Lets say I am disabling and enabling SIP on this server), creating this socket gives me error. I have debugged this issue and found the root-cause. Root-cause is when child is created it inherits (gets a copy of) all the opened fd/sockets from parent. when parent closes the tcp socket it still opened in child (ref_counter!=0)  and thus I cant open the socket again in parent!!

Now, the generic solution i want is - As soon as a child process is started it checks any opened fd (of type IPv4/TCP) and close them so that there is no side effect of this child process on parent. How can this be done in C-unix ? 
I have contemplated about doing in the direction of system(lsof | grep  | awk) and get the file descriptors, but then how do i close them ? 
Any other solution to close the socket in child ? Is there a method where I can pass port number and it gives me already created fd ?

Solution which I dont want are (Which will not be helpful for me ) -
1. In parent process, initially while creating tcp socket with some flag so that they are not copied by child. (I can not modify that socket creation in parent)! 
2. Passing file descriptor from parent to child at the time of creation of child process. I can not do that as I dont have that fd. The solution has to be something which needs to be put in child process!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible without editing the parent process code. Whenever I've had this problem I've used your solution 2 which you don't want.

Comment: One possible approach, if using Linux: Check the links in /proc/<pid>/fd/. Close the descriptors that link to 'socket:[inode]'.

Comment: I suspect you have mis-diagnosed the root cause and are now looking at two undesirable solutions to a problem of your own making.  It should be trivial for the children to close the listening socket first thing and for the parent to close the data socket immediately after the fork.

Comment: @MichaelBrennan - Thanks. I was just confused if those links (They are just number which I would parse using awk of the output of either lsof or /proc/<pid>/fd) can be directly passed to close(int fd). But, I just tried it and it works.

Comment: OP, no offense, but if you are using awk to parse lsof to close sockets in a C program you are headed straight off the rails.  You need to consider a redesign or give a really compelling reason why this is necessary.

Comment: @Duck Why do you say so ? Any other method to find out the socket fds which are inherited from parent (Is your objection is just about awk) ?  Again, please note that this child process is not being created to handle client-server architecture. This child process is created to handle some non-critical diagnostics of the SIP server which is the parent process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to determine in your child whether your file descriptors are sockets.

Since the child is going to inherit the fd table, just iterate through the FDs testing each one. The child in the following program gets the max size of the fd table via `getrlimit` and iterates through the table determining if each file descriptor is (a) open, (b) a socket and if so (c) if it is a listening socket.  The parent just opens a listening and regular socket (for test purposes) before forking and then waiting on the child.

You should be able to use this outline to accomplish your goal without resorting to awk and the like.

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>


int isListeningSocket(int fd)
{
    int retval;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(retval);

    if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &retval, &len) != -1)
        if (retval)
            return(1);

    return(0);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //create a listening socket
    int lsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serverinfo;
    memset(&serverinfo, '0', sizeof(serverinfo));
    serverinfo.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverinfo.sin_port=htons(atoi("9999"));
    serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

    int ret;

    if ((ret = bind(lsock,(struct sockaddr *) &serverinfo, sizeof(serverinfo))) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ret = listen(lsock,1000)) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    //create a regular socket
    int rsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid) //parent
    {
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }

    //child ----------

    struct rlimit rlim;

    if ((ret = getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlim)) == -1)
    {
        perror("getrlimit");
        exit(1);
    }

    int maxFD = rlim.rlim_cur;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxFD; ++i)
    {
       struct stat statbuf;

       if (fstat(i, &statbuf) == -1)
           if (errno == EBADF)
           {
               printf("file descriptor %d is not open\n", i);
               continue;
           }
           else
           {
               perror("fstat");
               exit(1);
           }

       if (S_ISSOCK(statbuf.st_mode))
           if (isListeningSocket(i))
              printf("file descriptor %d is a LISTENING socket\n", i);
           else
               printf("file descriptor %d is a REGULAR socket\n", i);
       else
           printf("file descriptor %d is NOT a socket\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary. The child has the same data in. Same variables as the parent after the fork(). All the child has to do is close 'lsock' or whatever it's called in the code, and all the parent has to do is close 'csock' or whatever it's called in the code. What your 'rsock' is for escapes me entirely.

Comment: @EJP - I know.  I said that two days ago but this is what OP insists he wants to do.

Comment: @EJP - it would not have escaped you if you took 10 seconds to consider it before making a unwarranted and rude down vote.

Comment: @Duck Thanks a lot. Though, I couldn't try this till now as I am out of town, But yes, getrlimit and fstat are something which will help me and is the right solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have the file descriptors. Just close the ones you don't need!

In the child you should close the listening socket.

In the parent you should close the accepted socket (=the new connection).

Answer (score 3):

Children inherit their parents' open file descriptors (this also includes sockets). In your case, the child process also has the socket open and bound to the port above. Thus, no other process (in normal case) can listen on this port anymore. What you need to do is to close the socket in the child (or, in case you don't need it before `fork()`) close it in the parent prior to forking.