# Is this the correct way to close socket descriptors on fork?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, fork, tcpclient

Consider this code:

```
socket_fd = start_server(port);

while (1){

    new_socket_fd = accept_client(socket_fd);

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){

        //I am the child server process

        close(socket_fd);      <------(1)

        do_stuff_with_client(new_socket_fd, buffer);

        close(new_socket_fd);       <------(2)

        exit(0);

    } else if (pid > 0){

        //I am the parent server process

        close(new_socket_fd);      <------(3)

    } else {

        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

From what I understand, when a process calls fork(), its address space is duplicated but not shared, so if I change variables or close file descriptors from child's process, it doesn't affect the parent.

That said, after the server has accepted a new connection (thus creating `new_socket_fd`) it forks itself, and the child closes `socket_fd` (1) because it's not required since the parent is still listening at its `socket_fd`.

The child processes the requests and then closes its `new_socket_fd` (2) and exits.

While the child is doing all of these, the parent process has already closed `new_socket_fd` (3) since the connection is being handled by the child.

The question is: are these assumptions right?

Comment: Yes.  That looks correct and the reasoning is sound.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler umm... quick question - so when / where does the parent process close `socket_fd`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler before the child closes the `socket_fd` is the bound port mapped to both the PIDs? If there is a incoming packet, whose queue will it be put into?

Comment: @babon In this case since it's an endless loop, never. The server will always be listening for up to N connections defined in listen(socket_fd, N).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya to the parent's one I assume

Comment: @Matteo if that is the case, the same should also happen for the packets for the `new_socket_fd` since both have it open. This means that the child won't be able to read the packets until the parent closes it. This can lead to race conditions.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya But file descriptor shouldn't intefere betweeen parent and child, that's why closing socket_fd on the child side doesn't stop the parent from listening

Comment: @Matteo Agreed. But I think you should close `socket_fd` after the `while` loop. In case tomorrow you change the loop to break for some condition you run the risk of keeping an open socket for no reason.

Comment: @Matteo both the file descriptors in the parent and child are different. So closing one should not affect the other. But both the copies have the same (src-ip, src-port, dest-ip, dest-port) 4-tuple and so where would a packet with such a header go?

Comment: The parent closes the `socket_fd` when it exits the loop or has been told to stop listening on the socket.  There's no real provision for that in the code shown, so it will be closed when the parent process is killed (or a fork failure occurs).  The whole point is that the listening socket can be used for many connections — you don't want to close it in the parent until you've finished listening.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In my example accept_client creates the sockaddr struct for the client, so the 4-tuple goes to child's new_socket_fd

Comment: Note that the `N` parameter in the `listen()` call is the number of outstanding connections that can be queued for the listening process.  That is, the number of connection requests that have not yet returned a value via the `accept()` call.  It is not a limit on the number of connections that can be active concurrently after the `accept()` has accepted the connection.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: _before the child closes the socket_fd is the bound port mapped to both the PIDs? If there is a incoming packet, whose queue will it be put into?_ The incoming packet is associated with the socket's 'open file description' (or equivalent — as distinct from 'file descriptor' or 'socket descriptor'). It is available to either parent or child, whichever reads it first. Similarly, incoming connection requests are queued on the `socket_fd`; they could be accepted by either parent or child. However, the family has agreed who does what so they don't get in each other's way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah! Whoever reads it first makes sense. Following this question I checked some other questions and some answer mentioned that the socket would be unusable to both. Hence the confusion. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Do you want to identify the question(s) that led to the confusion?  Maybe they need some fix-up work — a new answer, or some comments clarifying what is said, or something similar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19319981/2858773) answer. But now that I read it again, it is about listening to the port and not reading.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I've added a comment dissenting from what that answer says.  It was written years ago; it may take a while for the OP to do anything about it — if they ever do anything about it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually the context of that question is different. The OP there is forking and then closing the socket in the parent (for unrelated reasons) and then trying to listen again (to resume the service) but is unable to do so because the port is already bound in the child. The answer uses the word listen not accept. So maybe it is correct. The child process holding a copy of the socket is disallowing the parent to listen again.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: OK; I'll go back and have another look.  If you're correct (and I've no reason to think not), then I'm glad I didn't down-vote.  That would be adding insult to injury. _[…time passes…]_ I've removed my comment.  Although it isn't mentioned, the error is probably EADDRINUSE, because the address is in use.  And the parent/daemon design is faulty.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah Yes! and the SO rule about not being able to un downvote after 5 mins unless an edit is made is a pain sometimes.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: One advantage of lots of rep is that you can edit without troubling the review queues, so you can un-down-vote.  Not a desirable thing, but it does get you out of a fix on occasion.  I'm just a (very) cautious down-voter.  I seldom down-vote.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I would avoid that too. Anyway, thanks for taking time to answer all queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Converting the comment stream into an answer.*</sup>

#### TL; DR

Yes. The description in the question looks correct and the reasoning is sound.

At some point, your parent process should wait for child processes that have died to prevent the accumulation of zombies (but it shouldn't block until a child dies).  Using [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) in a loop with the `WNOHANG` argument is probably appropriate, in the portion of the loop where the parent closes the `new_socket_fd`.  This could leave one or more zombies around until the next incoming request is made.  If that's a problem, you could ignore `SIGCHLD` (so zombies are never created), or you could arrange a periodic wake-up during which the parent process checks for zombies.

#### Discussion

[babon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4845636/babon) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77351441_45190328)

> Quick question - so when / where does the parent process close socket_fd?

The parent closes the `socket_fd` when it exits the loop or has been told to stop listening on the socket. There's no real provision for that in the code shown, so it will be closed when the parent process is killed (or a fork failure occurs). The whole point is that the listening socket can be used for many connections — you don't want to close it in the parent until you've finished listening.

[Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238305/matteo) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77351554_45190328)

> In this case since it's an endless loop, never. The server will always be listening for up to N connections defined in `listen(socket_fd, N)`.

Note that the N parameter in the `listen()` call is the number of outstanding connections that can be queued for the listening process. That is, the number of connection requests that have not yet returned a value via the `accept()` call. It is not a limit on the number of connections that can be active concurrently after the `accept()` has accepted the connection.

[Ajay Brahmakshatriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858773/ajay-brahmakshatriya) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77351472_45190328)

> Before the child closes the `socket_fd`, is the bound port mapped to both the PIDs? If there is a incoming packet, whose queue will it be put into?

The incoming packet is associated with the socket's 'open file description' (or equivalent — as distinct from 'file descriptor' or 'socket descriptor'). It is available to either parent or child, whichever reads it first. Similarly, incoming connection requests are queued on the `socket_fd`; they could be accepted by either parent or child. However, the family has agreed who does what so they don't get in each other's way.

Matteo [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77351585_45190328)

> To the parent's one I assume.

Ajay [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77351665_45190328)

> If that is the case, the same should also happen for the packets for the `new_socket_fd` since both have it open. This means that the child won't be able to read the packets until the parent closes it. This can lead to race conditions.

This is based on a misunderstanding.  The packet is available to both processes via the file descriptor.  When a process closes the file descriptor, it can no longer access the information sent to connection (or send data on that connection, of course).  Until then, it is a lottery who sees what unless the participant processes agree on which one reads the data and which one listens for connections

Matteo [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77352107_45190328)

> But file descriptor shouldn't interfere between parent and child; that's why closing `socket_fd` on the child side doesn't stop the parent from listening.

babon [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77352171_45190328)

> Agreed. But I think you should close `socket_fd` after the while loop. In case tomorrow you change the loop to break for some condition you run the risk of keeping an open socket for no reason.

This is good practice, but the loop doesn't exit (it is a `while (1)` loop, and the failure mode does a `return` out of the loop — it could close the socket before doing that `return`).  And if the program exits, then the system closes the socket, so it isn't crucial, for all it is good housekeeping to close what you open.

Ajay [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77352301_45190328)

> Both the file descriptors in the parent and child are different. So closing one should not affect the other. But both the copies have the same (src-ip, src-port, dest-ip, dest-port) 4-tuple and so where would a packet with such a header go?

The descriptors are different, but the socket connection they refer to is the same.  The packet is available to any process that reads it — parent or child.

Matteo [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190328/is-this-the-correct-way-to-close-socket-descriptors-on-fork?noredirect=1#comment77352650_45190328)

> In my example `accept_client` creates the `sockaddr` struct for the client, so the 4-tuple goes to child's `new_socket_fd`.

This isn't quite accurate.  First, `accept_client()` is called before there is a child; the `new_socket_fd` is in the parent (only) when that function completes.  Second, after the `fork()`, both processes have access to the `new_socket_fd`, and either could read the data sent by the client process.  However, the program is designed so that the server goes back to listening for more connection requests while the child processes the incoming connection on `new_socket_fd` — a sensible division of labour.

Note that it would be permissible to have the parent process the request and the child continue listening.  However, this is contrary to convention.  It would mean that the 'daemon' process listening changes PID on each connection request, making it hard to determine which process is currently listening on the socket.  The conventional approach used in the code is that the daemon process remains the same over long periods of time, making it sensible to record the PID for later process control (killing the daemon when it isn't needed any more).

Comment: "The packet is available to both processes via the file descriptor. When a process closes the file descriptor, it can no longer access the information sent to connection (or send data on that connection, of course). Until then, it is a lottery who sees what unless the participant processes agree on which one reads the data and which one listens for connections" That's the main point I think, also other answers on the topic point out the problem of zombies, so I'll take a look about later on. Thanks for the recap.